# Display username in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

So I'm having user profiles for users and I'm using PHP. So I have my login and sign up that direct the info to the database, but now how would I have the username displayed in the URL. Here's a random Ask.fm profiles URL `http://ask.fm/janiecebrady` As you can see `janiecebrady` is shown in there. Would I get the username from the database and use `GET` then use `.htaccess` to get a pretty URL? How would you go about this?

Comment: This is done using routing.

Comment: That's helpful... @Tyranicangel

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html

Comment: I'm not talking about showing the pretty URL, rather just get the username in the url to start with. @blo

Comment: Yeah, in the tutorial the username can be read using `$_GET`

Comment: I get `Notice: Undefined index: username in /Users/idrisk/Colourity/si/r.php on line 53` When I try to use 
`$key=$_GET['username'];` @blo

Comment: Plus what would `users.php` and so fourth be? Giving me a link isn't very helpful

Comment: Are you trying to get the username from ask.fm or your host?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51062/discussion-between-blo-and-user302975)